# Audio export fail iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to concatenate two audio files with the following code:

```
func concatenateFiles(audioFiles: [NSURL], completion: (concatenatedFile: NSURL?) -> ()) {
    // Result file
    var nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let track = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    // Add each track
    for audio in audioFiles {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audio.path!), options: nil)
        if let assetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).first {
            let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: asset.duration)
            do {
                try track.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: assetTrack, atTime: nextClipStartTime)
                nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, timeRange.duration)
            } catch {
                print("Error concatenating file - \(error)")
                completion(concatenatedFile: nil)
                return
            }
        }
    }

    // Export the new file
    if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documents = NSURL(string: paths.first!)

        if let fileURL = documents?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(stringFromDate(NSDate())).m4a") {
            // Remove existing file
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(fileURL.path!)
                print("Removed \(fileURL)")
            } catch {
                print("Could not remove file - \(error)")
            }

            // Configure export session output
            exportSession.outputURL = fileURL
            exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
            // Perform the export
            exportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() { handler -> Void in
                if exportSession.status == .Completed {
                    print("Export complete")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        completion(concatenatedFile: fileURL)
                    })
                    return
                } else if exportSession.status == .Failed {
                    print("Export failed - \(exportSession.error)")
                }

                completion(concatenatedFile: nil)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i've receive this error exporting the file:

```
Export failed - Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media.})
```

i've try to change the format but doesnt work, i have no more idea,
there's some one can help me?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the passthrough preset here?

Comment: sorry, i've change this too, the correct is AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why, but the problem was solved when i change the attribution of the outputURL in the exportSession,

before:

```
exportSession.outputURL = fileURL
```

now:

```
exportSession.outputURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(fileURL.path!)
```

Comment: Sure, because forming a URL "by hand" as you were doing does not make a valid file URL.

Comment: @matt I am trying the same. I am concatenating audios and exporting them through AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough preset which i dont want to change to M4a because m4a takes long time to export for large audios. I tried above solution by wrapping fileurl in NSUrL but I still get the same issue.